# Foundation Shrub Planting in September

Tags: shrubs, planting, landscaping

I live in North Texas (North Dallas area).  I have put off re-planting some shrubs/bushes that were killed off in last year's deep freeze.  If I plant appropriate shrubs at this point in the year in the next week or two, will they tend to survive? My question assumes a normal fall and winter temps -- ~35-40 °F with occasional dips below freezing -- not another black-swan event like last year.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, before October, suitable plants for the area will have time for some root development before any chance of frost in the soil. They should be watered a few times during winter as they will have limited root systems to get water. Surface mulch will slow or moderate ground freezing at the plantings. Deciduous plants that have dropped leaves should be no problem at all. I am in a warmer location ( zone 8), I prefer autumn planting except the garden shops have limited choices. And, some of those choices are plants that have been in the shop for months and just barely survived ( not in vigorous condition like typical spring stock).